# VC++ error while installing Python module

Tags: python, visual-c++, module

I have Anaconda distribution of Python 2.7. I want to operate a Basler camera. Since OpenCV doesn't give such possibility, I downloaded a [Python wrapper](https://github.com/mabl/PyPylon) around a code, which will allow me to operate it. However, I have problems installing this wrapper. I have installed "VC++ for Python" but when I run the "install" command from the anaconda command window, I get the following errors. What am I doing wrong? I have Windows 10 64bit.

```
[py27] C:\Users\DDV\Downloads\PyPylon-master\PyPylon-master>python 
setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pypylon.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pypylon.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pypylon.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pypylon.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pypylon.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'cython\version.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'cython\factory.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'pypylon.cython.factory' extension
C:\Users\DDV\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG "-IC:\Program Files\Basler\pylon 5\Development\include" -IC:\Users\DDV\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\DDV\Anaconda3\envs\py27\include -IC:\Users\DDV\Anaconda3\envs\py27\PC /Tpcython\factory.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\cython\factory.obj
factory.cpp
C:\Users\DDV\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
c:\users\DDV\anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
C:\Program Files\Basler\pylon 5\Development\include\Base/GCTypes.h(77) : error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types
        C:\Users\DDV\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\stdint.h(87) : see declaration of 'int8_t'
C:\Program Files\Basler\pylon 5\Development\include\GenApi/GenApiLinkage.h(40) : warning C4081: expected ')'; found '('
C:\Program Files\Basler\pylon 5\Development\include\GenApi/GenApiLinkage.h(41) : warning C4081: expected ')'; found '('
C:\Program Files\Basler\pylon 5\Development\include\pylon/PylonUtilityIncludes.h(44) : warning C4081: expected ')'; found '('
C:\Program Files\Basler\pylon 5\Development\include\pylon/PylonIncludes.h(101) : warning C4081: expected ')'; found '('
cython\factory.cpp(3141) : warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
error: command 'C:\\Users\\DDV\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this Python wrapper in the current version can be installed with Python 3.5 only. So to succesfully install this package, Python 3.5 with Visual Studio Community edition is required. After installing the package, it works without any problems and creates an interface between python and Basler cameras.